# R installation issues

Tags: r

How to resolve issue in my R installation?

> Error: could not find function "read.csv"
> [Previously saved workspace restored]

I'm expecting to see R run freely in my console without saying it can find the function read.csv

Comment: Check the base library(utils), because this is a base function in R. If the problem is persistent, reinstall R and Rstudio.

Comment: *[Previously saved workspace restored]*  means you have a file named `.RData` in your working directory. That is the file's full name, not an extension. Try ending your R session, remove that file and rerun R.